# Should I use 'an' YOY or 'a' YOY or can i use without 'an' or 'a'?

Tags: grammar

The bank, which was ranked 30th in terms of profit, reported 44.84 percent year-on-year (YOY) decrease in profit at Rs4,254.24 crore. The bank was ranked third in terms of assets with a YOY increase of 9.55 percent at Rs11,64,853.75 crore,

In the above paragraph, in the second sentence I used 'a YOY'. I have a doubt should it be 'an YOY' or can I just ignore both 'an' and 'a'

---

The doubt pertains to, if we pronounce YOY as year-on-year, then it sounds like vowel. But if we pronounce YOY as why-o-why, then it doesn't sound like  vowel

Comment: "if we pronounce YOY as year-on-year, then it sounds like vowel" - I would very much like to understand how you pronounce _year_ starting with a vowel sound.

Comment: The obvious solution is not to use "YOY" if you're not sure how it's going to be pronounced. It adds nothing and saves nobody any effort.

Answer (score 3):

If you say *YOY* as "year on year" then it starts with a /j/ sound [that's the IPA *j*, not the English *J* which is IPA /dʒ/]. The /j/ sound is consonantal.

If you say *YOY* as an initialism, "why-oh-why", then it starts with a /w/ sound. The /w/ sound is consonantal.

If you say *YOY* as its own single word, /jɔɪ/, then it starts with a /j/ sound. The /j/ sound is consonantal.

Thus the correct article for *YOY* is **always** *a* and **never** *an.*

Comment: Great. thank You.